# The best security configuration to run MySQL opens for connection over the internet

Tags: mysql, server

I would like to install `MySQL` on a `VPN` instance (server) and I would like to connect to this `MySQL` over the internet.
What's the best practice to achieve this solution?
What's the best `MySQL configuration` for security because this `DB` will be visible from the internet?
Thank you for your hints and suggestions.

Comment: There are many many articles out there on how to do this. Google for "mysql security". Here's one that sounds like it's what you're looking for: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps

Comment: Thank you for the link @Andy Lester Yes, you got it right, there are too many articles on the internet too many!  But I'm looking for some checked solutions with the community of professional programmers, and want to span all the answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no MySQL configuration that is sufficiently safe or secure to allow connections over the unprotected internet. Don't do it.

At all of my past jobs, we never exposed the MySQL port on the internet. We used firewalls and routers and VPN's, so MySQL was accessed only by clients within our secure network. That secure network may include different sites, but it was all routed over inter-site WAN links and VPN's, not over the unprotected internet.

---

Alas, today I just saw this report about insecure MySQL instances whose ports are exposed to the internet: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/over-36-million-mysql-servers-found-exposed-on-the-internet/

Comment: I asked this kind of question because, when launching Amazon RDS MySQL,
there is an option to assign to DB a public IP address, so the DB can be publicly accessed.
So, I assume in some extreme scenarios, you need to have public access over the internet to DB. If so, there is some configuration you have to apply to it.

Comment: At every company I have worked at, we set a policy that _no_ RDS instance should have a public IP address assigned. We actually created an alert so that if any engineer inadvertently did that, we'd notice and get it corrected. Really, if you allow public internet clients to find your RDS instance, it is certain to be hacked or at least the traffic intercepted.